# Post Score vs. Age App?

Tags: discussion, app-request

Has anyone put together a script to generate the score vs. age of a question?

If this script were run on all questions in a particular tag, the curve generated by taking the average over a time window would be a useful proxy for the "ease of entry" for a particular tag. For example, I participate in the MATLAB, Python, and C++ tags, and there is extreme variation in the degree to which weaker questions are tolerated.

Weak questions in MATLAB are generally met with supportive comments; unless the user clearly isn't trying at all. Decent questions from somewhat-skilled users are routinely down-voted into oblivion in C++.
I'd like to try to graphically represent that difference.

So, do you know of anything like this? If not, I'm going to get working on it.

Comment: This is probably more a job for SEDE than the API.  Closest I've seen to what you want is [this votes/time graph](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152476/148310).